# Replace and Compress instead of either or

Tags: php

Using `ob_end_flush()` the output from PHP is compressed and is immediately output.

Using `ob_get_clean()` the output can be combined with `str_replace` however it does not compress the output (`echo str_replace($find,$replace,ob_get_clean();`).

How do I combine *both* the functionality to do a find and replace and compress the content to be served?

Comment: Maybe you can take a look at this on php.net? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-flush.php#109837 That is if you want to output after replacing. Otherwise maybe you can look into ob_get_contents and call flush afterwards.

Comment: Surely the best way to do this is to make sure the output contains the correct data in the first place.  Generating output and then changing the values seems like there is something wrong with the process flow.

Comment: @NigelRen Even the best generalization is still a generalization.

Comment: As there is no code in your question to show what/why you do anything, then generalizations is about as much as can be said at times.

Comment: @NigelRen To remove justification for pointless unrelated comments which people *still* insist on making.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue required a better understanding of the functions and their relations and the depth. I replaced `ob_get_clean()` with `ob_get_contents()` and then (I believe) closed the first output buffering via `ob_end_clean()`.

Then with the output buffering closed I opened it again, this time with compression enabled and everything works great now!

```
<?php
ob_start();//Start the initial buffer, do NOT use compression here.

//Content output here.

$c =  str_replace($find,$replace,ob_get_contents());//String replacement.
ob_end_clean();//Close buffering.

ob_start('ob_gzhandler');//Start a fresh buffer with compression.
echo $c;//Output the original buffer.
ob_end_flush();//Send to the client.
?>
```